# javafx Store value of a KeyTyped in a String

Tags: java, javafx

I want to store the value of an event "setOnKeyTyped" in a String (to use it later) but when I affect the character of the keyEvent to my string I have an error:

"local variables referenced from an inner class must be final or effectively final"

```
 String chiffre = new String();

 b.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
   public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
     chiffre = ke.getCharacter());
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to set the value of a local variable from a method in an anonymous class. If you want to keep the value, you need a member variable, not a local variable.

Try setting your code like this:

```
private String chiffre = "";

//...

public void yourMethod()
{
    //...
    b.setOnKeyTyped(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
       public void handle(KeyEvent ke) {
         chiffre = ke.getCharacter();
       }
    });
    //...
 }
```

EDIT: You had an extra ')' after ke.getCharacter()